# Regex Match special characters between two characters

Tags: regex

So I have the following requirements:

1. Any alphabets between a-z or A-Z
2. The first character must be alphabet
3. No numeric characters are allowed
4. No special characters are allowed except these three: .-‘
5. And they can only be in between letters

So far, to solve this I have got the 2 following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$
```

This is to solve points 1,2,3

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])[.\-'](?=[a-zA-Z])
```

and this is to solve points 4,5

Test cases can be words like:

- abc (pass)
- abc's (pass)
- abc' (fail)
- abc ' (fail)

However I am unable to combine them. I have tried and I do not get the expected outcome. Any ideas?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-.'][a-zA-Z]+)*$`

Comment: Thank you! And for the quick response

Comment: Your question stated "any alphabet". [a-zA-Z] will not match accented languages, such as German. It may be better to use the Unicode category \p{L} (or \p{Lu}, \p{Ll}) provided  your regex flavour provides support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-.'][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8Do9y/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:[-.'][a-zA-Z]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `[-.']` - a hyphen, dot or single quote
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string